# How do I create a global string variable, set it somewhere, and fputs it to a file?

Tags: c, syntax

I'm new to the C language although I hear its very similar to c++ since c++ is kind of an add on to C?

I can't seem to get a global variable (empty string) to be set in a method and then printed to a text file.

I've tried a few things, but based on what seems to make sense and worked for me in other parts of my program.. this is where I'm at:

```
char fileReqName[1024] = "";//trying to create the global variable
//code lines and methods
//theres a pointer that point's to a "token" thats a string.. called pptr
strncpy(fileReqName, pptr, sizeof(pptr));

//in another method:
fputs(fileReqName,file_ptr);
```

But it's not working.

It's supposed to be getting a "filename" from a browser request. Sometimes it's cutting the name of the file the browser goes to into a smaller string and sometimes its not displaying anything. It could be a problem with the token, but when I was displaying it before, the token was always correct.

I also just tried:

```
strcpy(fileReqName, pptr);
```

which seems to work sometimes as well haha. I think I might have to check the other code for why it's not displaying the correct string/path?

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is not working, or, what is happening instead?

Comment: How is `pptr` initialized?

Comment: The size given to `strncpy()` should be related to the size of the target string, not usually the source string.  A normal invocation might be `strncpy(fileReqName, pptr, sizeof(fileReqName)-1); fileReqName[sizeof(fileReqName)-1] = '\0';` where the assignment ensures that the string is null terminated (`strncpy()` does not guarantee null termination).  Occasionally, you want to copy a substring of `pptr`, but if you need that, you could use `memmove()` or `memcpy()` rather than `strncpy()` and then null terminate (because again, `strncpy()` does not guarantee null termination).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disagree with the 3 posted answers and submit another solution.  The primary use of the `n` parameter is to insure the destination `s1` is not overrun.

```
// prototype
#include <string.h>
char *strncpy(char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2, size_t n);
// Recommended usage for OP
char fileReqName[1024];
fileReqName[sizeof(fileReqName) - 1] = '\0';
...
strncpy(fileReqName, pptr, sizeof(fileReqName) - 1);
```

This will perform the usual `strcpy()` function with 2 added prevention features.
1 Even if `strlen(pptr)` is 1023 or more, only the first 1023 are written, preventing a buffer overwrite.
2 Should #1 occur, the `\0` assignment will insure `fileReqName` ends with a `\0`.

---

The first solution suggested `strlen(pptr)`.  This creates all sorts of issues as the `\0` byte is not copied to `fileReqName`, leaving it potential unterminated.  It does not prevent overruns.

---

The problem with `strncpy(fileReqName, pptr, (strlen(pptr) + 1))` is that is does not prevent buffer overrun in `fileReqName`.  Really no different than `strcpy(fileReqName, pptr)`.

---

The `printf()` solution describes well the issues in the OP's trial solution, but does not supply what the OP should do.

Answer (score 4):

If `pptr` is a pointer, `sizeof(pptr)` is probably 4 bytes.  That would copy 4 bytes into `fileReqName`.  You need to copy the length of the string, not just `sizeof(pptr)` (something like `strlen(pptr)`).

Comment: I did sizeof(fileReqName), but it wouldn't run

Comment: It depends on what `pptr` is actually pointing at.  That's what you have to verify.

Answer (score 2):

From the man page of `strncpy`:

```
char * strncpy ( char * destination, const char * source, size_t num );
```

Where:

```
num
Maximum number of characters to be copied from source.
size_t is an unsigned integral type.
```

Here you are using `sizeof(pptr)` instead of `strlen(pptr)`. Take a look at this simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char * pptr = "this is a string literal";
  printf("pptr = '%s', sizeof(pptr) = %ld, strlen(pptr) = %d",
         pptr,sizeof(pptr),strlen(pptr));
}
```

Output:

```
pptr = 'this is a string literal', sizeof(pptr) = 8, strlen(pptr) = 24
```

Answer (score 1):

*strncpy* copies **n** characters from the second parameter to the first... If the length of the second parameter is more than **n** you are no copying the null terminator... If you do *strlen(pptr)* you get the length of the string without the null terminator too!... then you will get some unpredictable results trying to use **fileReqName** in other functions like *fputs()*. You need to try:

```
strncpy(fileReqName, pptr, (strlen(pptr) + 1));
```

but it's the same as *strcpy* do...